# Add product details when publish a product (WordPress)?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-hook

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'send_new_post', 9876543210, 3);

function send_new_post($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
    
    if('publish' === $new_status && 'publish' !== $old_status && $post->post_type === 'product') {
        
            
        global $wpdb;
        
        $current_product_id = $post->ID;
        
        if(isset($current_product_id)) {
            $post_id = $current_product_id; 
        } else {
            $post_id = '131';
        }
        
        
        $sql = "SELECT 
                    post_id as id,
                    (SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE id = pm.post_id) AS title,
                    (SELECT post_name  FROM wp_posts WHERE id = pm.post_id) AS name,
                    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = pm.post_id AND meta_key = '_price' LIMIT 1) AS price, 
                    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = pm.post_id AND meta_key = '_regular_price' LIMIT 1) AS 'regular_price', 
                    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = pm.post_id AND meta_key = '_stock' LIMIT 1) AS stock, 
                    IFNULL((SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = pm.post_id AND meta_key = '_sku' LIMIT 1),
                    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = pm.post_id AND meta_key = '_custom_field' LIMIT 1)) as sku


                    FROM `wp_postmeta` AS pm
                    JOIN wp_posts AS p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
                    WHERE p.ID = ".$post_id." AND meta_key in ('_product_version')
                    AND p.post_status in ('publish')";
            
        $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

        $result = json_decode(json_encode($results), true);
        
        $data_init = $result[0];

        $tablename=$wpdb->prefix.'product_init';
            
        $data=array(
            'post_id'       => $data_init['id'],
            'post_title'    => $data_init['title'],
            'post_name'     => $data_init['name'],
            'price'         => $data_init['price'],
            'regular_price' => $data_init['regular_price'],
            'sku'           => $data_init['sku'],
            'stock'         => $data_init['stock'],
            'created_by'    => 'Created By Custom Code' 
        );
        
        $wpdb->insert( $tablename, $data);
        
        
    }
}
```

**Somehow i only get this**
[image]

**I can understand by i am not getting other values price, regular_price, sku, and stock ..........**

Comment: need help... bump

Comment: got my solution